# Change bootstrap color class every loop in Laravel (blade)

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a limited data list (only displaying the top 5). I'd look like this :

[image]

And the problem is how to make the icon in different color using Bootstrap class. I want the icon in that list have 5 color like bg-light-primary for the first, bg-light-danger for the second, bg-light-success for the third, etc. The way I display the data is using Laravel @foreach. Like this:

```
@foreach ($diklats->where('status', 'Active')->take(5) as $diklat_list)
    <div class="transaction-item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-dark">
            <div class="media">
                <div class="avatar bg-light-primary rounded">
                    <div class="avatar-content">
                        <i data-feather="book" class="avatar-icon font-medium-3"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body ml-1">
                    <h6 class="transaction-title">{{$diklat_list->name}}</h6>
                    <small>{{$diklat_list->userDiklat->where('is_approve',1)->count()}} </small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    <div class="font-weight-bolder text-danger"></div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

In this is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\{Diklat, User, UserDiklat, Regency};
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $diklat = Diklat::where('status', 'Active')->count();
        $participant = User::where('is_participant', 1)->count();
        $regency = Regency::all()->count();
        $diklats = Diklat::with('userDiklat')->get();

        return view('admin.index', compact('diklats', 'diklat', 'participant', 'regency'));
    }
}
```

I have search for this case but still didn't get it and
I'm in the learning stage. Would you help me, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: how do you want to display the icon colour? is there any criteria or just random?

Comment: You can use an @if statement on `$loop->index`

Comment: is it possible to set it with jquery + laravel? the color that i want to display is from bootstrap class, (ex: bg-primary, bg-danger, etc) @VPC

Comment: Why would you do it with jQuery? It can be done with php/blade since it does not change after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this:

```
  @php ($icons = ["bg-light-primary","bg-light-success","bg-light-danger","bg-light-warning", "bg-light-info"])
  <div class="avatar {{$icons[$loop->index]}} rounded">
    <div class="avatar-content">
      <i data-feather="book" class="avatar-icon font-medium-3"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an array of your values and use a random value from that array to use that as a class.

```
<?php $class_array = array("bg-primary","bg-danger","bg-success","bg-warning"); ?>
<div class="avatar-content">
    <i data-feather="book" class="avatar-icon font-medium-3 {{$class_array[array_rand($class_array)]}}"></i>
</div>
```

It is recommended that you should not use random class as it might repeat or all of them could be same at a time.

Comment: Why use random values anyway? First 5 should be bg-light-primary, next 5 bg-light-danger etc.

Comment: Switch on `$loop->index` instead of random